# Why Box2D body doesn't collide?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I does some tests with Box2D and stuck with it.
Here is my body-construct code:

> ```
>         var bodyDef:b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
>         bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
>         bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
>         var center:Number = Consts.stageToB2(Consts.worldSize / 2);
>         bodyDef.position.Set(center, center);
> ```

```
        var body:b2Body = physicWorld.CreateBody(bodyDef);

        var shape:b2CircleShape = new b2CircleShape(Consts.stageToB2(w) * 0.5); // our monster is in circle shape.
        var fixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;

        body.CreateFixture(fixtureDef);
```

I created such two bodies, but they doesn't collide! the debugDraw also doesn't light up the bodies. but when I add an angular velocitiy for one of them:

> body.SetAngularVelocity(Math.PI / 89);

They'll start collide. Could you explain What happens here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that Box2D won't check for collisions between objects that haven't had any forces applied to them. It seems logical because why would the engine waste resources to check those objects if they're not doing anything.

If you're placing the objects atop each other and then expecting something to happen without a gravity set or applying any forces to the boxes, that could be why.

Comment: I want to simulate an universe, so there's none gravity in my game. I tried to control player's ship by change its position. Anyway, when I apply a force as you suggest, they did collide with each other! So in Box2D, I've to always use Force or Impulse instead of directly set body's position, right?

Comment: @wanting252 Yes, make sure you apply forces and don't directly modify the position of the bodies. If you do that, there aren't velocities and so on attributed with the body to make use of in a collision. Basically to create a realistic reaction you need realistic movement. Objects in real life don't suddenly teleport to a new x and y coordinate when they move.

Answer (score 1):

What about gravity? If they are not moving at all , even not falling , it seems like you don't have a gravity in your world..

```
private var gravity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0, 9.8);
...
private var your_world:b2World = new b2World(gravity, true)
```

Comment: Yes, My game simulates the feeling of an universe, so there's none gravity. So gravity is a must to have collision in Box2D?

Comment: Absolutely no , but in this case you need to use forces on your bodies. If there is no gravity and there are no forces on bodies - bodies "sleeping"